# Toolbar is not hidden after segue

Tags: ios, iphone, uitoolbar, uistoryboardsegue

I have trouble w/ hiding toolbar when leave screen by segue.

**Details**: App has a few dozen screens, all of them are belonged the same navigation controller. A few screens have toolbar. For these a few screens in `-(void)viewDidLoad` I use

```
[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:NO];
```

and in `-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated:`

```
[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

so toolbar is visible only on necessary screens and the screen which needs toolbar controls the visibility. All work well when I navigate by "back" button. 
The trouble starting when I try to navigate by segue like this (goto home & goto another branch).

```
[owner.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:SEGUE_NAME sender:self];
```

toolbar is stay visible in spite of calling `-(void)viewWillDisappear` which should hide toolbar.

are there any ideas how to perform these "ToolBarHidden" by right way.

thanks

PS: of course I could hide toolbar on every screen, but I want to avoid this unnecessary operations and want to know how to do it right.

Answer (score 1):

`**STEP1:**` in your `controller.h`

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {

    UIToolbar *bar;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIToolbar *bar;

@end
```

`**STEP2:**` in your `controller.m`

```
@synthesize bar;

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

        [super viewDidAppear:animated];
        self.bar.hidden = NO;

}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {

        [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
        self.bar.hidden = YES;
}
```

`**STEP3:**` connect in Intrface

[image]

hope this help you!

Comment: thanks but my question is not about setting hidden property of toolbar.

Comment: ops i don't understand your question, want you move the tool bar when tap on back view (slide animation)? or you have problem on show a toolbar, can you post a screen of your interface?

Comment: problem is toolbar isn't disappeared when operations popToRootViewControllerAnimated() & performSegueWithIdentifier() executed consequently. Actually, it's navigation by drop-down menu.